# How can I tell whether a js object from Rhino's getProperty() is a sclar, NativeObject is a NativeArray?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm processing a complicated JSON data structure.

I get a property:

```
Object value = currentProperty.getProperty(propertyName);
```

Now, in JSON/JavaScript, that value can be a string, or an array, or an object.

**Is there a way in Java for me to tell the difference, before casting to NativeArray, or to NativeObject?**

I'd like to avoid:

- Dropping back to JavaScript and checking prototypes
- Doing a "attempted" cast to NativeArray, and try-catching if the cast fails.

I'm fine with using Reflection.

P.S. If it matters, I'm using Mozilla's Rhino, not Oracle Java's internal version of it.